# Please arrays, and loops

Tags: java, arrays

A. how do i write this simpler?

```
if (fclass[0] == 0 && fclass[1] == 0 && fclass[2] == 0 && fclass[3] == 0 &&  fclass[4] == 0 && fclass[5] == 0 && fclass[6] == 0 && fclass[7] == 0 && fclass[8] == 0 && fclass[9] == 0 && fclass[10] == 0){

}else{

}
```

B. **Solved!** How would i scan an array (atm all values in it are at 0), when i change some of the element are set to one and show only the ones that have a 0 still.

example:

```
if fclass[1], fclass[2], fclass[4], fclass[5], fclass[6], fclass[10],
        were all set to 1. How would i get my program to show me fclass[3], fclass[7],
        fclass[8], and fclass[9]?
```

Thanks for the help...

```
for (int f = 0; f <= fclass.length; f++){
                if (fclass[f] == 0){
                    System.out.println(fclass[f]);
                }
```

C. My teacher requires us to learn GUI but doesn't know it herself, any good websites to start learning that?

Comment: Please read through the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). This question is all over the place.

Comment: Learn [**loops**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm) first!  GUI can wait.

Comment: I understand loops, my friend said to use a loop for problem B., but i do not know how to get it to do that.

Comment: You can upvote each that you like, but can only accept one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A. You can set a boolean and loop through them to check if all are zero. I'm assuming that your fclass variable is int[].

```
boolean flag = true;

for (int i : fclass)
{
    flag &= (i == 0);
}

if (flag)
{
    // if all are zero...
}
else
{
    // if one of them is not zero...
}
```

B. Similarly you can loop through the array and scan what is not equal to zero.

```
for (int i : fclass)
{
    if (i != 0)
        System.out.println(i);    // these are array not equals to zero.
}
```

Comment: On a side note, you may also look at `ArrayList` as it provides more flexibility than native array, if in the end you'll still need an array you can do `arrayList.toArray();`.

Answer (score 0):

A.

```
boolean allZero = true;
for(int i=0; i<fclass.length; i++){
    if(fclass[i] !=0) allZero = false;
}

if(allZero){

}
else{

}
```

B.

```
for(int i=0; i<fclass.length; i++){
    if(fclass[i] ==0) System.out.println(i + "is 0");
}
```

C. Google

Answer (score 0):

A:

```
 boolean checkFClass(int[] flcass) {
  for(int i =0 ; i < 11; i++) {
   if(fclass[i] !=0) { 
    return false;}
   } 
   return true;
  }
```

B:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < fclass.lenght ; i++) {
 if(fclass[i] != 1) { System.out.println(fclass[i]);}
}
```